# How to store the result of query from createApi in a slice?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I just integrated to **`redux-toolkit`** . My goal is to store the result of the query `getPosts` in a `slice`, so I can use it across the site or change it.

My `createApi` is like this:

```
  export const postsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "posts",
  baseQuery: getGeneralFetchBaseQuery(),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPosts: builder.query<PostsType, number>({
      query: (id) => `api/posts/${id}`,
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetPosts } = postsApi;
```

I want to store the result from `getPosts` in this slice

```
export const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
});

export default postsSlice.reducer;
```

and my store is like this

```
export const mainStore = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    postsReducer,
    [postsApi.reducerPath]: postsApi.reducer,
  },
})
```

**How can this be achieved?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Let me preface this by: generally, you probably shouldn't.

RTK-Query is a full cache solution - so you should usually not copy state out of it in most solutions, but let RTK-Query keep control over that data.
If you want to change it, temporarily copy it over into local component state (this goes for all kind of form states by the way, you should not edit a form in-place in redux, but temporarily move it over to local component state), use a mutation to save it back to the server and then let RTKQ re-fetch that data to update the cache.
Wherever you need that data, just call `useGetPostsQuery()` and you're good - if that data is not yet fetched, it will get fetched, otherwise you will just get the value from cache.

Oh, bonus: you should not create an extra api per resource. You should have one single `createApi` call in your application in almost all cases - you can still split it up over multiple files using [Code Splitting](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-splitting).

All that said, of course you *can* copy that data over into a slice if you have a good use case for it - but be aware that this way you now are responsible for keeping that data up-to-date and cleaning it up if you don't need it any more. Usually, RTKQ would do that for you.

Here is an example on how to clone data from a query over into a slice, taken from the [RTKQ examples page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/examples#using-extrareducers):

```js
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: { user: null, token: null } as AuthState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      api.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled,
      (state, { payload }) => {
        state.token = payload.token
        state.user = payload.user
      }
    )
  },
})
```

Comment: Hi, @phry I am following extraReducer approach for the experiment. I m storing data to slice reducer when endpoint matchFulfilled. So if in my slice reducer there is post-1 and I change id to post-2 it fetches data and stores it. But if I again want to render post-1 from slice reducer, it's not able to fetch. As in cache layer, the endpoints request never gets fulfilled and it gets rejected bcz cache layer already has the data. So I am not able to change the data if I want to render post-1 because cached data request is never getting fulfilled in the cache layer thus no payload for a slice.

Comment: @phry Is there any way to store the cache layer data into a slice if the request is getting rejected due to the cache layer already having that data?

Comment: "Rejected" in this case means "a request was not even made". There is no data to store to the side because there is no request. If you want to trigger a new request on mount, despite data being in the cache, use the `refetchOnMountOrArgChange` option to your hook or the full api.

Comment: Hi @phry , I would like to know if the approach you suggested would be effective in cases where you need the query hook to refetch after a mutation has invalidated its corresponding tag?

Comment: @BravoStack Yes, you'll get data from future refetches this way, too.

Comment: @phry I actually tried it, but I did not get the desired result. Subsequently, I resorted to lazyQuery, upon a mutation's success. 
A did a little something like: 

```doSomething().unwrap().then(() => {lazyGetData().unwrap().then(() => {         dispatch(saveToSlice());}).catch(error => {  // error }); }).catch(error => { // error }); ```

I'm skeptical about its efficiency, hopefully you could guide me on that.

Comment: @BravoStack you really shouldn't be doing that manual lazyQuery stuff. The fulfilled matcher for your endpoint will match every refetch of that endpoint in the future - it's definitely the way to go.