# Why action doesn't properly dispatch using redux toolkit?

Tags: next.js, redux, redux-toolkit

I have this slice:

```
const studentSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'studentSlice',
  initialState: {
    data: {},
    loading: false,
    error: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    setData: (state, action) => {
      state.data = action.payload;
    },
    setLoading: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = action.payload;
    },
    setError: (state, action) => {
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
export const { setData, setLoading, setError } = studentSlice.actions;
export default studentSlice.reducer;
```

I have tried to create an action that uses multiple reducer:

```
export const getStudentData =
  (): any => async (dispatch: any) => {
    try {
      console.log("here");
      dispatch(setLoading(true));
      const {
        data,
        isLoading,
        error
      } = await personApi.endpoints.getStudentList.useQueryState(); // Using RTK Query
      console.log(data);

      if (isLoading) {
        return;
      }

      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }

      dispatch(setData(data));
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(setError(error));
    }
  };
```

In my Components, using `useEffect`, I am trying to dispatch the action

```
const StudentProfile = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getStudentData())
    }, [])
    
    const students = useSelector((state: any) => state.student.data))

    return ... // some components that use this students
}
```

But the `getStudentData` action doesn't execute (no log printed). Why this happened and how to dispatch the action properly?

---

I have recently tried using extraReducers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68612556/how-to-store-the-result-of-query-from-createapi-in-a-slice%20but%20the%20state%20of%20the%20slice%20doesn%27t%20change%20either) but the state of the slice doesn't change either.

---

Here is my API slice code:

```
const personApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getStudentList: builder.query<StudentsResult, void>({
      query: () => ({
        url: 'students',
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          // some fields
        }),
      }),
      providesTags: ['Students'],
    }),
  }),
});
```

Comment: You are using `personApi.endpoints.getStudentList.useQueryState()` within an action creator. RTK Query's auto-generated hooks (like `useQueryState`) are not intended to be used inside thunks—they are meant to be used directly in components. The `useQueryState` hook is meant to provide state directly to a component, not within a thunk.

Comment: Agree with @Batman. Your `getStudentList` endpoint generates the hooks you should be calling from the component. They also already have their own loading states baked-in. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want to store the data from createApi to the slice (redux store). I have updated the question with new approach but doesn't work too.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include your API slice code?

Comment: I have updated the question with the API slice code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to store the data from `createApi` to the [`studentSlice`] slice.

You can create reducer cases to match the pending, fulfilled, and rejected statuses of active queries/mutations.

```js
const studentSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'studentSlice',
  initialState: {
    data: {},
    loading: false,
    error: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    ....
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addMatcher(
        personApi.endpoints.getStudentList.matchPending,
        (state) => {
          state.loading = true;
        },
      )
      .addMatcher(
        personApi.endpoints.getStudentList.matchFulfilled,
        (state, action) => {
          state.loading = false;
          state.error = null;
          state.data = action.payload;
        },
      )
      .addMatcher(
        personApi.endpoints.getStudentList.matchRejected,
        (state, action) => {
          state.loading = false;
          state.error = action.payload;
        },
      );
  },
});
```

Initiate the `getStudentList` query using either the generated [`useGetStudentList`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usequery) or [`useLazyGetStudentList`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery) hooks.

```js
const queryResult = useGetStudentList();
```

```js
const [getStudents, queryResult] = useLazyGetStudentList();
```

Alternatively, if you *really* still wanted to use a Thunk, then use `createAsyncThunk` so the pending, fulfilled, and rejected actions are generated for you, and [initiate](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/endpoints#initiate) the endpoint manually. Note that since you *still* need the `extraReducers` that there's no net gain over the preferred method above using the query matchers.

Example:

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const getStudentData = createAsyncThunk(
  "students/getStudentData",
  async (_, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const { data, error } = await thunkApi.dispatch(
        personApi.endpoints.getStudentList.initiate()
      );

      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }

      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

```js
const studentSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'studentSlice',
  initialState: {
    data: {},
    loading: false,
    error: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    ....
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(getStudentData.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getStudentData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = null;
        state.data = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getStudentData.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action.payload;
      });
  },
});
```